# AnalogWrite not working in if statement

Tags: arduino-uno

Arduino Uno with ATMega328P `Processor.analogWrite` is not working properly in if statement. It changes the brightness of the LED as if there wasn't any if statement at all.

There are 2 potentiometers to create an intervall in which to program increases of the LED brightness, starting at 40% of the maximum. When it's lower than the minimum value, the LED is turned off.

```
int ledPin = 6;
int sensorPot = 1; // it's a potentiometer for now
int maxPot = 7; // potentiometer 
int minPot = 3; // potentiometer
int fortypercent = 255*0.4;
int brightness = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPot, INPUT);
  pinMode(maxPot, INPUT);
  pinMode(minPot, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int start = analogRead(minPot);
  int maxVal = analogRead(maxPot);
  int sensor = analogRead(sensorPot);
  Serial.println(sensor/4);
  Serial.println(start/4);
  Serial.println(maxVal);
  if(sensor/4 > start/4) {
    analogWrite(ledPin,sensor/4);
  } else if(sensor = baslangic) {
    analogWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  } else if ((start < sensor < maxVal)) {
    brightness = sensor/4 - fortypercent;
    analogWrite(ledPin,brightness); 
  } else if (sensor = maxVal) {
    analogWrite(ledPin , 255);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't execute how? What happens?

Comment: Of course it can. What problem are you having? What output do you expect from this program? What output do you have instead?

Comment: Sorry, edited question

Comment: Please, be more specific, like “If I set the pot XXX to position XXX I expect the program to do XXX and instead ot does XXX”.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 4):

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE, BASED ON DIFFERENT CODE**

You are comparing `sensorValue` to see if it's ever less than `minValue`.

However, you have mapped `sensorValue` to range from `0` to `255`, and `minValue` is set at `0`. How can anything from 0-255 be less than zero?

**NEW RESPONSE, BASED ON UPDATED CODE**

One of your `if` statements: `else if(sensor = baslangic)` is not comparing, but assigning `baslangic` to `sensor`. To compare, use `==`.

Your other `if` statement: `else if ((start < sensor < maxval))` is wrong. C++ doesn't work this way. Maybe you want: `if ((start<sensor) && (sensor<maxval))`?

Instead, your statement evaluates like `if ( (start<sensor) < (maxval) )`, which means you are comparing the `TRUE` or `FALSE` of `(start<sensor)` to the `int` that is `maxval`.

Comment: I am analog reading minValue.

Comment: Indeed. So, what is connected to pin `A3` (minPot) and what values from `analogRead()` is it providing? Use debug statements. I will retract this answer, since I misread the question.

Comment: Sorry for asking not well explained questions... Newbie here... Updated the question